# Which package is Python using?

Tags: python, package

I see that one could have several versions of a Python package installed:

```
$ locate signals.py | grep python
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/zim/signals.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/zim/signals.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/smart/signals.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/smart/signals.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/signals.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/signals.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/signals.py
```

How might I check which version of a package (i.e. which file, not which version number) an application is using? Ignoring the obvious "Zim will use the package at `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/zim/signals.py`" is there way to see which file is being used for a particular Python package?

Some packages I can crash and look at the backtrace. I don't think that this is the best method, however!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__file__` attribute will tell you:

```
>>> from unittest import signals
>>> signals.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/signals.pyc'
```

`.pyc` are compiled files, so the file you actually are looking for in this case it the `/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/signals.py` file.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood correctly, but here's how you find out the location of the module you loaded:

```
shell> python -c 'import jinja2; print jinja2.__file__'
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.pyc
```